# Symfony: i18n in generator.yml

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, yaml

Does anyone know if there's a possibility to use i18n in the generator.yml file like this:

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    ...
    config:
      edit:
        title: Editing Category xyz
```

Now I'd like to translate the title in my i18n files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work out of the box. All the form labels are passed through translation function automatically.

You need to enable i18n in your application and create translation files. Simple as that.

Assuming you have a backend application, to enable i18n edit your apps/backend/settings.yml:

```
all:
  .settings:
    i18n: true
```

Generate translation catalog for language(s) you need:

```
./symfony i18n:extract --auto-save backend fr
```

At the end you need to translate your messages. Simply edit generated apps/backend/i18n/fr/messages.xml.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I just enabled i18n for the frontend and forgot to do so for the backend.